# Windows 7 - change domain password from non domain computer

Tags: windows-7, active-directory

I think I saw a technique somewhere, that allows to do it from a command line (let's forget about Outlook Web for second, shall we?), but am not 100% certain ... Is it doable?

Comment: It's definitely doable; AD protocols, both old proprietary (SAMR) and new standard (LDAP, Kerberos), are well-known. But oddly, all commands I can remember are for Linux/Unixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the C source of a utility that does just that:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <lm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAXNAMELEN 200
#define MAXPASSWDLEN 50

#define RETVAL_SUCCESS 0
#define RETVAL_INVALID_CMDLINE 1
#define RETVAL_BREAK 2
#define RETVAL_VERIFY_ERROR 3
#define RETVAL_CHANGE_ERROR 4

#define CH_BACKSPACE  8
#define CH_ENTER     13
#define CH_BLANK     32
#define CH_ASTERISK  42

#define AnsiToUnicode(FROM,TO)           \
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP,          \
                        0,               \
                        FROM,            \
                        strlen(FROM)+1,  \
                        TO,              \
                        sizeof(TO))

#define OemToUnicode(FROM,TO)            \
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_OEMCP,        \
                        0,               \
                        FROM,            \
                        strlen(FROM)+1,  \
                        TO,              \
                        sizeof(TO))

UCHAR szAccountName[MAXNAMELEN];
UCHAR szDomainName[MAXNAMELEN];
UCHAR szSpecifiedAccountName[MAXNAMELEN];
UCHAR szSpecifiedDomainName[MAXNAMELEN];
UCHAR szOldPassword[MAXPASSWDLEN];
UCHAR szNewPassword[MAXPASSWDLEN];
UCHAR szVerification[MAXPASSWDLEN];

WCHAR wszAccountName[MAXNAMELEN];
WCHAR wszDomainName[MAXNAMELEN];
WCHAR wszOldPassword[MAXPASSWDLEN];
WCHAR wszNewPassword[MAXPASSWDLEN];

BOOL bQuiet=FALSE;
BOOL bInfo=FALSE;
BOOL bPasswordsSpecified=FALSE;
BOOL bUserSpecified=FALSE;
BOOL bDomainSpecified=FALSE;

void Usage(char *cmdname)
{
    printf("Usage: %s [-q] [-i] [-p oldpass newpass] [-u user] [-d domain]\n",cmdname);
    printf("       change password on the command line\n");
    printf("       -q (quiet)     suppress display of * while entering passwords\n");
    printf("       -i (info)      print account and domain information\n");
    printf("       -p (passwords) specify old and new password on the command line\n");
    printf("       -u (user)      change password for any other user (default: you)\n");
    printf("       -d (domain)    select a different domain/machine (default: your domain)\n");
    printf("       (C) 1997 by Alexander Frink (Alexander.Frink@Uni-Mainz.DE)\n");
    printf("                All rights reserved.\n");
    exit(RETVAL_INVALID_CMDLINE);
}

void ProcessCmdLine(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char c, *p, *arg0;

    // algorithm for command line processing taken from SDK sample 
    // Win32/WinNT/Floppy/MFMT.C

    arg0=argv[0];

    if ( argc > 1 ) { 
        while (--argc > 0 ) { 
            p = *++argv; 
            if (*p == '/' || *p == '-') { 
                while (c = *++p) {
                    switch (tolower(c)) { 
                    case '?': 
                        Usage(arg0);
                        break; 
                    case 'q': 
                        bQuiet = TRUE; 
                        break; 
                    case 'i': 
                        bInfo = TRUE;
                        break;
                    case 'p': 
                        if (argc<3) Usage(arg0);
                        bPasswordsSpecified = TRUE;
                        argc--, argv++; 
                        strcpy(szOldPassword,*argv); 
                        argc--, argv++; 
                        strcpy(szNewPassword,*argv); 
                        break;
                    case 'u': 
                        if (argc<2) Usage(arg0);
                        bUserSpecified = TRUE;
                        argc--, argv++; 
                        strcpy(szSpecifiedAccountName,*argv); 
                        break;
                    case 'd': 
                        if (argc<2) Usage(arg0);
                        bDomainSpecified = TRUE;
                        argc--, argv++; 
                        strcpy(szSpecifiedDomainName,*argv); 
                        break;
                    default: 
                        Usage(arg0); 
                        break; 
                    } 
                } 
            }
        } 
    } 

}

void GetUserAndDomain(UCHAR *szAccountName, UCHAR *szDomainName)
{
    HANDLE hProcess, hAccessToken;
    UCHAR InfoBuffer[1000];
    PTOKEN_USER pTokenUser = (PTOKEN_USER)InfoBuffer;
    DWORD dwInfoBufferSize, dwAccountSize = MAXNAMELEN, dwDomainSize = MAXNAMELEN;
    SID_NAME_USE snu;

    hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();

    OpenProcessToken(hProcess,TOKEN_READ,&hAccessToken);

    GetTokenInformation(hAccessToken,
                        TokenUser,
                        InfoBuffer,
                        1000,
                        &dwInfoBufferSize);

    LookupAccountSid(NULL,
                     pTokenUser->User.Sid,
                     szAccountName,
                     &dwAccountSize,
                     szDomainName,
                     &dwDomainSize,
                     &snu);
}

BOOL GetPassword(UCHAR *szPrompt,UCHAR *szPasswd)
{
/*
    this subroutine is partially (C) by
    Steffen Krause: skrause@informatik.hu-berlin.de,
    the author of SuSrv, a SU utility for Windows NT
    Improvements: allow correction of typing errors (with 'Backspace')
                  exit on CTRL-C (returns FALSE, otherwise TRUE)
                  skip non-printable characters (function/cursor/escape)
                  optional: suppress *'s while entering password
*/

    int i;
    int ch;
    i = 0;
    printf("%s",szPrompt);
    while(((ch = _getch()) != CH_ENTER) && (i < MAXPASSWDLEN))
    {
        if (ch==CH_BACKSPACE) {
            if (i>0) {
                szPasswd[i]=0;
                i--;
                if (!bQuiet) {
                    _putch(CH_BACKSPACE);
                    _putch(CH_BLANK);
                    _putch(CH_BACKSPACE);
                }
            }
        } else if (ch==3) {
            szPasswd[0]=0;
            return FALSE;
        } else if ((ch==0)||(ch==224)) {
            // probably function or cursor key, skip this and next character
            ch=_getch();
        } else if (ch==27) {
            // escape key, skip
        } else {
            szPasswd[i++] = ch;
            if (!bQuiet) {
                _putch(CH_ASTERISK);
            }
        }
    }
    szPasswd[i] = 0;
    return TRUE;
}

void PrintErrorMessage(NET_API_STATUS status)
{
    /*
    In contrast to the documentation on NetUserChangePassword
    (SDK 4.0 and VC++ 4.2), other error codes in addition to the listed
    NET_API_STATUS are returned. Therefore I decided to list all possible
    errors from winerror.h which have to do with passwords.
    */

    switch (status) {
    case NERR_Success:
        // nothing to do
        break;
    case ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED:
        printf("Error: The user does not have access to the requested information.\n");
        break;
    case NERR_InvalidComputer:
        printf("Error: The computer name is invalid.\n");
        break;
    case NERR_NotPrimary:
        printf("Error: The operation is allowed only on the primary domain controller of the domain.\n");
        break;
    case NERR_UserNotFound:
        printf("Error: The user name could not be found.\n");
        break;
    case NERR_PasswordTooShort:
        printf("Error: The password is shorter than required.\n");
        break;
    case ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD:
        printf("Error: The specified network password is not correct.\n");
        break;
    case ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORDNAME:
        printf("Error: The format of the specified password is invalid.\n");
        break;
    case ERROR_NULL_LM_PASSWORD:
        printf("Error: The NT password is too complex to be converted to a LAN Manager password.\n");
        break;
    case ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD:
        printf("Error: Unable to update the password. The value provided as the current password is incorrect.\n");
        break;
    case ERROR_ILL_FORMED_PASSWORD:
        printf("Error: Unable to update the password. The value provided for the new password contains values that are not allowed in passwords.\n");
        break;
    case ERROR_PASSWORD_RESTRICTION:
        printf("Error: Unable to update the password because a password update rule has been violated.\n");
        break;
    case ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE:
        printf("Error: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.\n");
        break;
    case ERROR_PASSWORD_EXPIRED:
        printf("Error: Logon failure: the specified account password has expired.\n");
        break;
    case ERROR_NT_CROSS_ENCRYPTION_REQUIRED:
        printf("Error: A cross-encrypted password is necessary to change a user password.\n");
        break;
    case ERROR_LM_CROSS_ENCRYPTION_REQUIRED:
        printf("Error: A cross-encrypted password is necessary to change this user password.\n");
        break;
    case ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN:
        printf("Error: The specified domain did not exist.\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Error: Undocumented error code %i.",status);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NET_API_STATUS status;

    ProcessCmdLine(argc, argv);

    GetUserAndDomain(szAccountName,szDomainName);
    if (bUserSpecified) {
        strcpy(szAccountName,szSpecifiedAccountName);
    }
    if (bDomainSpecified) {
        strcpy(szDomainName,szSpecifiedDomainName);
    }

    if (bInfo) {
        printf("Changing password for user '%s' on domain or machine '%s'...\n",szAccountName,szDomainName);
    }

    if (!bPasswordsSpecified) {
        if (!GetPassword("Old password: ",szOldPassword)) {
            return RETVAL_BREAK;
        }
        if (!GetPassword("\nNew password: ",szNewPassword)) {
            return RETVAL_BREAK;
        }
        if (!GetPassword("\nVerification: ",szVerification)) {
            return RETVAL_BREAK;
        }
        printf("\n");

        if (strcmp(szNewPassword,szVerification)!=0) {
            printf("Password verification failed!\n");
            return RETVAL_VERIFY_ERROR;
        }
    }

    AnsiToUnicode(szAccountName,wszAccountName);
    AnsiToUnicode(szDomainName,wszDomainName);
    OemToUnicode(szOldPassword,wszOldPassword);
    OemToUnicode(szNewPassword,wszNewPassword);

    status=NetUserChangePassword(wszDomainName,
                                 wszAccountName,
                                 wszOldPassword,
                                 wszNewPassword);
    if (status==NERR_Success) {
        return RETVAL_SUCCESS;
    } else {
        PrintErrorMessage(status);
        return RETVAL_CHANGE_ERROR;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try doing this with the `net user`-command. Try this:

```
net user USERNAME PASSWORD /domain YOURDOMAINNAME
```

or

```
net user USERNAME * /domain YOURDOMAINNAME
```

to get a prompt for the new password.

Comment: no such luck ... been there done that ...

Comment: Are you sure you have access to the DC from the computer you've got in mind? Try pinging the DC by using its internal name. If not, a firewall or vlan-separation could be the cause to your lack of success.

Comment: That's a negative. I can use everything on the domain, even hookup my Win7 credentials to various domain accounts.

Comment: I have found a utility that does just that. It is called passwd, written in C. Will post source shortly.